# Exchange2016/Meeting room booking conflict reply language change

Tags: mailbox, exchange-2016

Im not really sure whether this question should be asked in superuser or here, but in superuser i haven't received a working solution.

[image]
Above is the auto reply message when a domain user tries to book a meeting room using *Outlook*.

My question would be - how to change the language that is in this auto reply (circled in red)? Currently it is in russian and I would like it to be it in english. I haven't found any methods to do this via "Exchange management shell". I've also checked the language settings with the **Get-MailboxRegionalConfiguration** command via exchange management shell and it is set to en-US for all the meeting rooms and domain users who get this auto reply when they try to book a room.

Could this be the exchange server locale thath is somehow set to russian? If yes, how to check it and change it?

Thanks for any tips!

Answer (score 0):

Check the language/date format of the Organizer's email client, change English as the default one.

Here is a similar link，we may get a fix by adding a registry key.

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/exchange/en-US/168e9ada-8a73-4b88-9f10-5a3a1b49c719/meeting-room-emails-are-in-german-date-format-not-english?forum=exchangesvradminlegacy